# Logrotate says it rotates but does not

Tags: raspbian, logrotate

I have a strange issue with logrotate on a Raspbian 9 system.

Logrotate appears to be configured to rotate /var/log/syslog every seven days. When I run `logrotate -f -d /etc/logrotate.conf` the output tells me:

```
rotating pattern: /var/log/syslog
 forced from command line (7 rotations)
empty log files are not rotated, old logs are removed
considering log /var/log/syslog
  Now: 2021-03-16 09:56
  Last rotated at 2020-11-02 12:26
  log needs rotating
rotating log /var/log/syslog, log->rotateCount is 7
dateext suffix '-20210316'
glob pattern '-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
compressing log with: /bin/gzip
renaming /var/log/syslog.7.gz to /var/log/syslog.8.gz (rotatecount 7, logstart 1, i 7),
renaming /var/log/syslog.6.gz to /var/log/syslog.7.gz (rotatecount 7, logstart 1, i 6),
renaming /var/log/syslog.5.gz to /var/log/syslog.6.gz (rotatecount 7, logstart 1, i 5),
renaming /var/log/syslog.4.gz to /var/log/syslog.5.gz (rotatecount 7, logstart 1, i 4),
renaming /var/log/syslog.3.gz to /var/log/syslog.4.gz (rotatecount 7, logstart 1, i 3),
renaming /var/log/syslog.2.gz to /var/log/syslog.3.gz (rotatecount 7, logstart 1, i 2),
renaming /var/log/syslog.1.gz to /var/log/syslog.2.gz (rotatecount 7, logstart 1, i 1),
renaming /var/log/syslog.0.gz to /var/log/syslog.1.gz (rotatecount 7, logstart 1, i 0),
log /var/log/syslog.8.gz doesn't exist -- won't try to dispose of it
renaming /var/log/syslog to /var/log/syslog.1
creating new /var/log/syslog mode = 0640 uid = 0 gid = 4
running postrotate script
running script with arg /var/log/syslog: "
                invoke-rc.d rsyslog rotate > /dev/null
"
```

So it says it is renaming `/var/log/syslog` to `/var/log/syslog.1` and creating a new `syslog`. So everything appears to be ok so far.

Just, it does noting. There is no syslog.1 afterwards and the syslog file is the same as before. Nothing happened.

One thing to mention: /var/log is  tmpfs- is this related?
Mounted as: `tmpfs on /var/log type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime)`

Thanks for ideas!

/KNEBB

Comment: Since this is a systems administration problem, rather than a programming one, you're likely to find better answers on one of the other sites in the network: https://superuser.com https://unix.stackexchange.com or https://askubuntu.com

Comment: Yes, I mixed it up. sorry for this.
And to update the issue here: I was so dumb not reading. When running in debug mode (as done above) logrotate does nothing- it just tells you what it would be if run without "-d".

Answer (score 1):

And to update the issue here: I was so dumb not reading. When running in debug mode (as done above) logrotate does nothing- it just tells you what it would be if run without "-d".